# Microservices architecture design

Tags: microservices

I am new to microservices and currently run into a problem, there are two services, vehicle and historical service, when user disable a vehicle through the vehicle service, I want users to query the historical data to exclude the disabled vehicle data, but the two services use their own databases, how should I design to make it better?

Comment: Depends a lot on the circumstances, can you easily add an event stream to your service(s)? That is the standard way of solving this kind of communication problem, in which a service publishes the event: "Hey something happened to me" and it is up to listeners to decide how to react. In this case the something is "vehicle disabled" and the historical data service is very interested in this event (as it can use it to exclude/hide that vehicle from queries)

It comes with its own nest of problems though, so you will have to carefully consider the use cases before you decide an implementation

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

I'd recommend you to use a message control if your system will be more complex.

Something such like the Rabbit MQ:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/

Using a message system to control your microsservices is an alternative to maintain data consistensy and keep the microservices isolate